# Reading timeuuid value from Cassandra - Using DataStax connector

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

Im using the `datastax 3.2.0` connector.

When I try to read a column of data type `timeuuid`, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [timeuuid <-> java.lang.String]
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to insert string into timeuuid field.**

Convert the string to uuid before insert

```
String your_string = "38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d";
UUID uid = UUID.fromString(your_string); //Use this uid to insert
```